# Select an Index From a Variable in SQL

Tags: sql, variables

Trying to see how indexes work in SQL. This is not a table, but more of a list? In C# or other languages, we have arrays with `array[i]` being the syntax for getting a specific item. How would I grab IDs number 5? This is basic code, which I plan to put into something bigger, such as an incrementing `for` loop to increment through each of these IDs. Purpose: DELETE from record history table takes too long and impacts production. Looking to batch this out into smaller transactions to delete obsolete records.

```
DECLARE @Cust_NoHolds TABLE(IDs VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '0'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '1'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '2'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '3'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '4'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '5'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '6'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '7'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '8'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '9'

SELECT IDs FROM @Cust_NoHolds WITH (INDEX(1)) --this is obviously wrong
```

Comment: You can do this with row_number except that because DB tables don't have an order (unlike arrays) you need to sort them. What would you be sorting by? I'm assuming you're doing something more interesting than your sample data would suggest

Comment: What fields comprise the (natural, not surrogate) primary key of the table? Use those for the DELETE operation. The surrogate key values will often be somewhat sparse, as they are only guaranteed to be unique and monotonic, not sequential.

Comment: The variable is storing a list of IDs that meet certain criteria within a table, so they will not be sequential. Perhaps a temporary table is a better method for storing these? I am open to suggestions.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem - a question on how to improve an inadequate proposal to an unknown business problem. Please explain the true business problem you are faced with.

Comment: This is a simple question, no need to get into business specifics. "How to simulate an array in SQL" is all I am asking. It's a basic data structure, and I am just trying to see how to handle it in SQL, explicitly or otherwise.

Comment: @RyanHaley . . . Your question is misguided.  Indexes do not control the order of the result set for a SQL query; nor do they affect the actual results.  They are an internal optimization.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Correct, but it can be implicitly structured using an ID column.

Answer (score 3):

A relational database table has no natural order - unlike an Array which has one item logically after another, a database row has no relationship to another row. It looks like it does when you select data, because it's stored and retrieved in some way but that is a result of the implementation by the database.

So in database terms it doesn't really make sense to say delete row 5, but it can make sense to say delete the 5th row that appears when I sort the data by column XXX. Although in practice what you tend to say is delete the row (or set of rows) where column XXX has value YYY.

You can think of an index as imposing some kind of order on a table (that isn't really their main purpose though).

Comment: Not the answer, but this definitely explains a lot about the datastructures behind SQL. So let's say I have this variable, and i have a for loop with an incrementer, and let's also assume the numbers within are not sequential as is in the example. Should select the top one and delete the top one when I am finished with it? I think this would implicitly increment the "array".

Comment: Also, unless the indexed fields comprise a super key for the table, it is indeterminate whenever a tie occurs.

Comment: @RyanHaley: ***There is no array***. As long as you continue to imagine that there is you are not going to solve your real problem.

Comment: That was just a term, I am no longer looking at it as an array, but now a messy desk of papers.

Comment: @RyanHaley: Do you grasp the significance of primary keys in a relational database yet? It's not clear that you do.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I understand the significance, no need to be condescending. I guess I am just a little miffed that SQL doesn't possess the ability for arrays, AS ALL OTHER LANGUAGES DO. I have written in all levels of languages, and it's a little strange that SQL doesn't even implement the array structure as an option. That being said, with code, anything can be simulated or augmented with some form of workaround.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens To make it even more clear, a SQL Table is an array, in nature, such that it does have indexes. I think a new table will be created to support my needs, and it will resolve my issue. Do you know how other languages work? It's not clear that you do.

Comment: @RyanHaley: The point to SQL is specifically to **not** be an array - because the array concept for databases, as for example used by ISAM databases of the 50's through 70's, was found to be total inadequate. The internal structure of each table, whether heap or tree or dictionary, is explicitly and deliberately hidden because that structure simply didn't work for databases.

Comment: SQL differs from other languages in many ways.  If your experience is with functional/ object oriented /procedural languages you could find overlapping names confusing.  Indexes in SQL aren't the same as in C, for example.  They share a name but not a concept.  Likewise while tables appear to be a array-like objects they are not (other comments explain why this is).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to track insertion order on a table, then use an `identity` column:

```
DECLARE @Cust_NoHolds TABLE(
    id int identity,
    IDs VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Then for an insert, use an explicit column list:

```
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds(ids) SELECT '0' --crude, but basic. forgive me.
```

Now, you have a monotonically increasing number that has the insertion order.  So, one way of getting the fifth record is:

```
select *
from @Cust_NoHolds
order by id
offset 4
fetch first 1 row only;
```

For `offset`, 0 is the first row so 4 is the fifth row.  This syntax is available in SQL Server 2012+; in earlier versions you would need to use `TOP` twice with a subquery.  Also, the `order by` is important because the result set -- like the table -- is unordered unless an `order by` clause specifies the ordering.

Note that the identity columns are guaranteed to be increasing, but they could have gaps.

Comment: I like this answer, too. The "sort by" forces some sort of guaranteed order, and offset can be used with the incrementer in the loop. I wish you had gotten here sooner, as this thread is much messier than it ever needed to be.

Comment: Actually I am using 2008, so this "offset" is not available. However, I will store my values in a new table and just perform this in batches based on the tables ID, IDs.

Comment: **Identity** columns track *insertion attempts*, not *insertion successes*, and do not renumber following deletions. One should be explicit about this, as many newbies don't get this readily.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens . . . There are other reasons why gaps might appears as well, although failed attempts is a common reason (as are deletes and "reserved values" in a parallel environment).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Correct; so it is not a "sequential number" but rather a *monotonically increasing number*.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens . . . I changed the phrasing.  Personally, I think the two terms are synonyms, but I'm willing to grant that in the popular imagination, "sequential number" might have a hint of having no gaps.  And, isn't it cool to use the phrase "popular imagination" and "sequential number" in the same sentence?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to leave the mess in here to provide an example (and a reminder to myself) that no matter how long we have been coding, there are always lessons to learn. I'd like to give a huge thanks to Conrad Frix, Pieter Geerkens, Gordon Linoff, and destination-data for making me look at this from another angle. My goal was to batch this large task into smaller tasks that I could manage in separate individual queries. Below is what I have come up with, which works perfectly for what I am looking to accomplish. Thanks again to the aforementioned contributors to this thread, and every one else too for trying. The below uses the SQL architecture to an advantage over an array, and is seemingly more efficient than my "array simulation" prototype.

```
DECLARE @Cust_NoHolds TABLE(IDs VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds
SELECT  DISTINCT CI.Custodian_Id
FROM            custodian_info          CI
--WHERE "stuff" (it's a massive union of two massive join statements)

DECLARE @historyIDs TABLE(histIDs VARCHAR(100)) --New values with each batch run!
INSERT INTO @historyIDs
    SELECT  Custodian_History_Id
    FROM    custodian_history   CH
    WHERE   CH.Custodian_Id IN (Select IDs FROM @Cust_NoHolds)

--SELECT * FROM @historyIDs ORDER BY histIDs --takes 29 seconds to get to this point

DELETE  custodian_history
FROM    custodian_history   CH
WHERE   CH.Custodian_History_Id IN (Select TOP 100 histIDs FROM @historyIDs) --TOP X represents my batch
--Re-running this full sql file will take on the next X IDs in sequence, effectively making a functional batch.
```

Comment: I'll go a little further and say that I will be managing the batch queries using PowerShell, but that's for another thread. ;)

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Thanks

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: Thanks

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Thanks

Comment: @destination-data: Thanks

Comment: You might want to check out *tally tables*, also known as *numbers tables*: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Answer (score 0):

One method is to limit the number of deleted records using [TOP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175486(v=sql.105).aspx).

**Sample Data**

```
/* Table variables making sharing sample data easy.
 */
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        Id        INT
    )
;

INSERT INTO @Sample
    (
        Id
    )
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3)
;
```

This query was built and tested in SQL Server 2008 R2.  If it doesn't work for you add the correct product tag to the question.

```
/* You can limit the number of records that are deleted.
 */     
DELETE TOP (1)
FROM
    @Sample
;

/* Two of the original three records will remain.
 * There is no guarantee which these will be.
 */
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @Sample
;
```

This query deletes one of the three sample records and returns the other two.  You could combine with a [WHILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms178642.aspx) until all the required records have been removed.

**EDIT:**  You might find a better approach is to identify why the original query is underperforming.  [Stack DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) may be able to help, if you can provide a query plan and some context.

Comment: In response to why the query is underperforming, it's referencing this varialbe of tens of thousands of values to delete from another table (FK_Reference) with over 2.7 million entries. I just watched it run for 24 hours, with no end in sight. I think this batching will be more efficient...maybe. If I have to, I can make a temporary table to store these values, and release them when the work is completed.

Comment: Where do the variables come from?  Are they are stored within the db?  The problem with this kind of approach is it undermines the set based nature of SQL.

Comment: I'll keep it simple. I have a table with users and user IDs, and another table which records all changes made to these users. Some of these users don't need to be in the system anymore, but in order to delete them from the table, there is a foreign key constraint that prevents that deletion. I have gone through and deleted all entries from other tables that possess these foreign key constraints, but this last one is huge (2.7 million entries). Apparently it ran for 24 hours without completing, so now I am looking at batching these deletions by ID number, one by one.

Comment: I'll post another answer that shows how you delete the contents of one table based on another.  This set based approach should perform better.

Comment: I know how to do this, it's just that it is apparently taxing to do it all at once. - 

DELETE custodian_history FROM custodian_history CH WHERE CH.Custodian_Id IN (Select IDs FROM @Cust_NoHolds)

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify the records you want to delete from another table, or tables, you can move this logic into your delete statement.  This approach avoids looping, which doesn't play to SQLs strengths.

The examples use two tables.  @Target is the table we will delete from.  @ToDelete contains rows we no longer require in @Target.

**Sample Data**

```
/* Table variables making sharing sample data easy.
 */
DECLARE @Target TABLE
    (
        Id        INT
    )
;

DECLARE @ToDelete TABLE
    (
        Id        INT
    )
;

INSERT INTO @Target
    (
        Id
    )
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3)
;

INSERT INTO @ToDelete
    (
        Id
    )
VALUES
    (1),
    (2)
;
```

In the example I've filtered @ToDelete to limit the records that are deleted.

**Example**

```
/* You can use the WHERE clause to filter the 
 * records you are going to delete.
 */
DELETE
FROM
    @Target
FROM
    @Target AS t
        INNER JOIN @ToDelete AS td        ON td.Id = t.Id
WHERE
    td.Id = 2
;

/* Id 2 has been removed.
 * It appeared in both tables and the WHERE clause of the DELETE statement.
 */
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @Target
;
```

Answer (score -1):

Despite the bickering about how to use arrays in SQL, here it is, kids...an "array" in SQL. 
SQL Server 2008

```
DECLARE @Cust_NoHolds TABLE(ID INT, IDs VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '0', '1234'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '1', '1225'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '2', '1256'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '3', '1287'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '4', '1212'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '5', '1290'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '6', '1350'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '7', '1334'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '8', '1631'
INSERT INTO @Cust_NoHolds SELECT '9', '1953'

DECLARE @I      INT
DECLARE @J      INT
SET @I = 0
SET @J = (SELECT COUNT(IDs) AS Cust_NoHolds FROM @Cust_NoHolds)
WHILE @I < @J
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @Cust_NoHolds WHERE ID = @I
    /*Delete Statement
        DELETE  custodian_history
        FROM    custodian_history   CH
        WHERE   CH.Custodian_Id IN (SELECT IDs FROM @Cust_NoHolds WHERE     ID = @I)
    */
    SET @I = @I + 1
END
```